# Drawing on Tkinter Canvas: No "Create" Attribute

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, line, draw

I am trying to draw a line on a Tkinter canvas on command. Whenever I run the program, however, I receive this error:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_create'`

Here is the relevant code. I only included the portions dealing with this line, so it is not complete:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, Canvas, BOTH


#Functions

def drawLineHandler():
    print("Draw Line")
    canvas.create_line(15, 25, 200, 25)

#Call Root Window

root = Tk()

#Declare Variables

canvas = Canvas

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()   
    self.initUI()


def initUI(self): 
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

#Menu Code

menuBar = Menu(root)
root ["menu"] = menuBar

lineMenu=Menu(menuBar)


menuBar.add_cascade(label="Line Builder", menu=lineMenu)
lineMenu.add_command(label="Draw Line", command=drawLineHandler)

#Main Loop

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it does: `canvas = Canvas`.

Comment: `Canvas` is a widget class, so you need to call it and create an instance of one before drawing anything on it. See [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your Canvas object is not in the window tkinter is creating with your line root= Tk(). so you need to add the following

```
#you need the brackets here at the end of Canvas
canvas= Canvas()
canvas.pack()
```